# Extjs combobox - doQuery callback?

Tags: combobox, extjs

I'm using the following combobox:

```
            var cb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            store: someDs,              
            fieldLabel: 'test',
            valueField:'name',
            displayField:'name_id',
            typeAhead: true,
            minChars: 3,
            triggerAction: 'query'
        });
```

So when the user typed in 3 chars, a query to the server is made showing the proper results.

Now I try to make the user input programmatically usint the doQuery() function of the combobox. After calling the doQuery() method, I want to seledct an Item via setValue().

```
        cb.doQuery('myval');
        cb.setValue('myval');
```

The problem is that setValue() can't select the propper value, because at the time it is called, the request started through doQuery() hasn't finished.
So I need something like a callback in which I could use setValue() - but doQuery() doesn't seem to have a callback function.

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Hm, maybe it is an option to use the 'load'-event of the store assigned to the combobox:

someDs.store.on('load',function() {
    cb.setValue('myval');
});
cb.doQuery('myval');

But I'm not sure if this is an elegant solution...

Comment: This is one of the options I was thinking of. Does it work the way you want?

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering myself bacause code formatting ist not avaiable in the comment.

Igor: it works but it feels like a ugly hack then a clean solution.
For a better understanding I explain the situation:
I have a GridPanel. When the user clicks on a row on this panel, I want to preselect the selected value in the combobox. Because there's a lot of data I want to lower it with using the doQuery-function of the combobox.
In the GridPanel's rowClick-event i have the following code:

```
var myrec = Ext.getCmp('mygrid').store.getAt(rowIndex);

mycombo.store.on('load', myfn1 = function() {
    // When the store has finisihed loading, select item in the combobox
    mycombo.setValue(myrec.data.customer_id);
    // Remove the function assigend to the load event... 
    // ...(when user types directly to the combobox instead clicking on a row...)
    mycombo.store.un('load', myfn1);
});
// setValue has to be called again, because the load-event doesn't fires
// when doQuery is called with same params
mycombo.setValue(myrec.data.customer_id);
// Call do query to fill the combo only with the relevant values
mycombo.doQuery(myrec.data.customer_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox` has a `beforequery` event that gives you the option to intercept the query, do your own store load instead and cancel the `ComboBox` query. Also, in your example you are saving the handler function to a variable and then calling `un` from within the handler. That's totally unnecessary, as you can pass the options `{single: true}` as the fourth parameter to `on` (third parameter is `scope`).

If I understand your question, you want to set the value of a combo to a certain value, say customer id `123`. The problem is that the record for customer `123` is not loaded so you don't have any data in the store regarding that customer. Am I right?

What you would want to do then is (this is not necessarily correct for your situation, just a direction to get you started):

```
combo.on('beforequery', function(q) {
  q.cancel = true;
  var id = q.query;
  combo.setDisabled(true);
  combo.store.on('load', function() {
    combo.setValue(id);
  }, combo.store, {single: true});
  combo.store.reload({
    customer_id: id
  });

  return q;
});
```